# Cleaner way to implement moving a div back and forth using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I am trying to setup a simple example where a user can click a button on a page and divs are moved from one side of a parent div to another.  If the button is clicked again the divs should move back to their original position.

I have successfully set this up, but the code feels a little clumsy to me.  Can anyone recommend a cleaner way to do this than what I have done below:

```
var operator = '+=';
$('#clickme').click(function() {

    $('#main div:even').animate({
        left:operator + '200'
    }, 2000);

    if(operator == '+='){operator = '-=';}
    else{operator = '+=';}
});
```

The if/else at the end of my click event is the part that seems odd to me.  Any suggestions for prettying this up?

You can play with the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/S6UtE/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would keep the `+=` and change the 200 to -200 and back again:

```
var move = 200;
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#main div:even').animate({ 
        left:"+="+move
    }, 2000);
    move = -move;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S6UtE/7/

Comment: +1, didn't think you could do a `+=-200`.  This is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you would consider this better or not?

```
var rightd = true;
$('#clickme').click(function() {

$('#main div:even').animate({ 
    left:(rightd ? "+=" : "-=") + '200px'
}, 2000);

rightd = !rightd;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S6UtE/6/

Answer (score 0):

You could have a 2-element array containing '+=' and '-=' at spots 0 and 1, and do something like this:

```
var operat0rindex = 0;
$('#clickme').click(function() {

  var operator = operators[operatorindex];

  //operatorindex = (operatorindex + 1) % 2
  //or more quickly/simply:
  operatorindex = 1 - operatorindex;

  $('#main div:even').animate({
     left:operator + '200'
 }, 2000);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You could use `jQuery.data()` to avoid a global var. Something like this:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
   var moved = $('#main div:even').data('moved');
   var operator = moved ? '-=' : '+=';
   $('#main div:even').data('moved', !moved);
   $('#main div:even').animate({
      left:operator + '200'
   }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: I just read @mblase75 solution, and it's really the way to go. I suggest you combine that with my no-global-var idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option that may not have been considered.

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#main div:even').each(function(index, element) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.animate({
            left: parseFloat($this.css("left")) >= 200 ? "-=200" : "+=200"
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```